# how to run specific tests from different suites in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I have created 2 different suites using robot framework
say

```
TestSuite1 which has tests
      TestCase1
      TestCase2

TestSuite2 which has tests
      TestCase3
      TestCase4
```

Now, I want to run Testcases in the following order

```
TestSuite2\TestCase4
TestSuite1\TestCase1
TestSuite1\TestCase2
TestSuite2\TestCase3
```

When I have searched in stack over flow forum, i got two different answers which are

Answer 1: create a Argument file with the suites names in which order want to run and run

```
Argument_File.txt
-----------------
TestSuite2
TestSuite1

pybot -A Argument_File.txt
```

Answer 2: To run specific test in a suite give the command

```
robot --test TestCase1 TestSuite1
```

But my purpose is different, i want to run the different testcases in different suites together in the order i wish.

Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks
Sarada

Comment: first thing, why would you keep testcases in such an order that 2 tests which have to be executed one after the other are in different suite? If you still want to achieve I am sure robot has enough feature to play with an achieve this. But main thing being why would anyone want to do this :)

Comment: If Not exactly like that even, if I want to run some test cases of suite1 and then some test cases of suite2 will serve my purpose. My purpose is like, If I want to run sanity kind then it will be useful for me

Comment: you can add same tags to the tests across different suites.. and when you run only those tests will be executed.

Comment: Hi waman, thanks for your reply, how to give this in Arguments file. because when i tried it accepted only suite names, for other things i am getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argument file

```
--include <tags>
<Suite1> 
<Suite2>
<Suite3>
```

This should run tests tagged with similar name across all your suites.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks waman it worked. With curiosity i am asking whether it is not possible to give `--test` in Argument file and execute particular testcases?

Comment: Definitely possible! arguments file is nothing but and external place from where you can pass your command line arguments. So every thing that works from command line, can be a part of your argument file

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want. All the tests in one suite will run before any tests in the next suite.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bryan, so sad that we doesn't have this option with Robot Framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can add tags to each test cases in your suite. Now, give same tag name to you second suite and while executing include this tag and run. Example: I have created two suites

```
Suite1
Test1
[Tags]  x  y

Test2
[Tags]  z  w


Suite2
Test1
[Tags]  w  y

Test2
[Tags]  x  z
```

And these suites are under some folder 'folder_1'. Now, if you want to run all the test cases which have tag x just type as below

```
pybot -i x folder_1
```

This will execute test1 from suite 1 and test 2 from suite 2.

Comment: Hi navy, thanks for reply. Is it possible to says two tags in that command for execution

Answer (score 0):

I found exact near functionality exist in RED plugin.

Install Eclipse (Mars or above version) + RED + RobotFramework-EclipseIDE

```
pom.xml --> right click --> Run As --> Run Configurations
```

Here we can select the test cases under different test suites.

but as waman mentioned, it will be one test suite after another.